# How to calculate a circle rotation or in other words twist angle?

Tags: plotting, circles

the following picture is part of a tube which I want to calculate the twist angle.

[image]

I have tried the following way. I separated the first 8 points belong to the very first and the last 8 points belong to the very last circle. I want to calculate the polar angle of an specific point on the first and last circle and calculate the twist angle.

```
 firstcircle ={{-0.834569, -0.714351}, {-0.11224, -1.03938}, 
 {0.591095, -0.816882}, \
 {-1.18714, 0.0352363}, {0.928852, -0.0502188}, {-0.817417, 
 0.760688}, {-0.0692644, 1.0556}, {0.65441, 0.696939}};

lastcircle ={{-1.78886, -0.469517}, {-1.23843, -1.05153}, 
{-1.86881, 
 0.358521}, {-1.31055, 0.947005}, {-0.409872, -1.00096}, 
 {-0.523629, 
  0.963112}, {0.144351, 0.437588}, {0.0988358, -0.388713}};


 ptsf = firstcircle
 cent = Mean[ptsf]; (*data mean,point on the best-fit plane*)
(*normal to best-fit plane*)
 nrm = Flatten[
 Last[SingularValueDecomposition[
 TranslationTransform[-cent] /@ ptsf, -1]]]
 {a, b1, b2, c} = 
 Flatten[Last[
 SingularValueDecomposition[
 Flatten[{Norm[#]^2, #, 1}] & /@ ptsf, -1]]];
 {cenf, rad} = {-{b1, b2}/(2 a), Sqrt[(b1^2 + b2^2)/(4 a^2) - 
 c/a]}
 fcirc = Graphics[{Red, 
 Circle[cenf, rad], {AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[ptsf]}}]


 pts = lastcircle
 cent = Mean[pts]; (*data mean,point on the best-fit plane*)
(*normal to best-fit plane*)
nrm = Flatten[
Last[SingularValueDecomposition[
TranslationTransform[-cent] /@ pts, -1]]]
{a, b1, b2, c} = 
Flatten[Last[
SingularValueDecomposition[
 Flatten[{Norm[#]^2, #, 1}] & /@ pts, -1]]];
{cen, rad} = {-{b1, b2}/(2 a), Sqrt[(b1^2 + b2^2)/(4 a^2) - 
 c/a]}
lcirc = Graphics[{Circle[cen, rad], {AbsolutePointSize[6], 
Point[pts]}}]

Show[fcirc, lcirc]
```

I am not sure how to shift one of the circles (plus the related points) on top of the other circle to compare their polar angle?

How to draw and compare the polar angles?

I appreciate any help regarding this problem.

[[image]]2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To shift the center of the lastcircle to the center of the firstcircle, you need to subtract the difference of the centers from the coordinates of the points of the lastcircle. Here is a graphics that illustrates this:

```
centf = cent = Mean[firstcircle];
centl = cent = Mean[lastcircle];
Graphics[{PointSize[0.02],Point[firstcircle], Red, 
  Point[(# - (centl - centf)) & /@ lastcircle]}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much